# CICD pipeline for LAMP stack application on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp, cicd

I have a LAMP stack application on EC2 instance. The code (PHP) for this is on AWS CodeCommit and currently all developers make changes and check their changes in to the repository on AWS CodeCommit.

The challenge is that someone has to take git pull on the server each time a developer checks in their code into the repository.

How can I setup a CICD pipeline so that when a developer checks in their code to a branch by merging their working branch into it, the code gets deployed to the EC2 instance as well without the manual effort.

Tried using AWS CodePipeline with CodeDeploy but it puts the application offline when deploying, it first packages it, pushes to S3, then deploys which takes long for changes to get onto the server.

Comment: "Tried using AWS CodePipeline with CodeDeploy but it puts the application offline when deploying, it first packages it, pushes to S3, then deploys which takes long for changes to get onto the server." It sounds like you need to configure multiple servers with a rolling deployment. Your question should really focus on how to prevent CodeDeploy from taking your application offline, instead of just asking "how to CICD".

Comment: No, Actually I just need to deploy the code on one server